# implement multiple interfaces in C#

Tags: c#

In my program, I have defined a couple of interfaces, like IInterface1, IInterface2, IInterface3, IInterface4, IInterface5, if I need implement all five interfaces in a concrete class, do you implement those interface directly like the following

```
public class EntityClass: IInterface1,IInterface2, *** IInterface5
{
}
```

or would you create an interface which inherits from those interface firstly, and then implement that interface?

```
public interface IEntity: IInterface1,IInterface2, *** IInterface5
{
}

public class EntityClass:IEntity
{
}
```

Comment: Both approaches seem ok to me. The second one is more reusable, though. For example if you need to implement `IEntity` in many different classes, and have your code treat `IEntity` as a single conceptual unit.

Comment: It depends on what needs to be exposed to consumers. Interface segregation is fine.. and if there is an "umbrella" interface that defines the contract of all of them.. that is also fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inheritance of interfaces expresses the "is-a" relationship.  You would inherit IEntity from IInterface1 if every implementation of IEntity must also be an IInterface1.

Yes: public interface IPanda : IBear

Probably not: public interface IAccountant : IObsessiveCompulsiveDisorder

Comment: funny on OCD :)  and my wife is a CPA :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your use case.

If your `IEntity` always contains the other interfaces then it would be a lot easier to make it implement the others.

If this is not the case, you'll have to abstract it in a way that no class has to implement methods it doesn't need, while also needing as few implements as possible.

That being said: if you'll only use this for one or two classes, you could just as well use a list of interfaces instead of grouping them in intermediate interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are valid in the context of good practice. However, it depends purely on your design. I find the best way to approach inheritance is to try and talk back what you are inheriting and make sure it makes sense.

For instance, "Is every EntityClass an IEntity?", which may be true. However, asking "Is every EnetityClass an Interface1, AND an Interface 2 etc.", which may be true for some instances, and not for others, but all are implemented on IEntity.

The problem with aggregating many interface implementations into one interface can be when you implement more classes off the interface that has many interfaces in itself is when the implementation needs only a few of the interfaces, in which case you need to re-work your design to ensure that the tree of inheritance makes sense.